# ejs and express public and private route's view pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Recently I am creating a website using express and ejs, so other than express and ejs, I will also have one css and one javascript file on the frontend, the site I am creating will have a dashboard which the user has to login first to see and use the dashboard so overall my site will have few public routes and two or three private routes(which user has to login to interact with).

**My question is not on performance point of view but on security point of view:**

For my frontend javascript file do I need to split into two files so one js file is for all the public routes pages and another one is for all private routes pages? if I just use one client side js file for both public and private routes view pages is there going to be any kind of security issues? because if I am only using one client side js file, I will also using that js file to manipulate different kind of DOM element in private routes(for example dashboard.ejs) too.

**Example:**

If I have two public route, index.ejs and about.ejs, when user visit those public route the server will send public.js to the client side, like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>index page</h1>
  <div>
  <script src="./public.js"></script> //This js file is used for all PUBLIC routes view pages
</body>
```

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>about page</h1>
  <div>
  <script src="./public.js"></script> //This js file is used for all PUBLIC routes view pages
</body>
```

and after user login and gain access to the private route view page which for example is dashboard.ejs, the server will send private.js to the client side, like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>dashboard page</h1>
  <div>
  <script src="./private.js"></script> //This js file is used for all PRIVATE routes view pages
</body>
```

Is there a need to use above way to avoid any kind of security issues or I can just use one client side js file to take care of all public and private routes view pages DOM manipulation etc...?

sorry if this question is kind of... I am still new to web development.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, security of data is achieved by requiring appropriate credentials on an incoming http request before sending any protected data in a response.  This isn't something that is achieved by hiding client-side Javascript files.  This is something that is achieved by enforcing credential checks on any http request that sends any protected data in an http response.

If your private.js just does DOM manipulations within the browser, then there may not even be any security reasons to protect it.  If the server does its job and refuses to send any protected data with appropriate credentials, then there's nothing a client-side only JS file can do to expose such data.

If private.js has some things you consider secrets in it, then we'd have to really understand what those are and what the risks are.  In most (perhaps all) cases those "secrets" should probably be moved to the server where they are also only operable or accessible when appropriate authorization credentials have been supplied.  Code on the server is where you hide "secret" things, not client-side JS files anyway.

> For my frontend javascript file do I need to split into two files so one js file is for all the public routes pages and another one is for all private routes pages?

This shouldn't really be about security.  Your JS files shouldn't contain important secrets. This should be more about code struture and organization for efficient operation (like not sending lots of code to a page that will never use it).

> if I just use one client side js file for both public and private routes view pages is there going to be any kind of security issues? because if I am only using one client side js file, I will also using that js file to manipulate different kind of DOM element in private routes(for example dashboard.ejs) too.

As mentioned earlier, JS that manipulates DOM elements shouldn't be considered secret code.  It doesn't, by itself, present any security risks.  The data needs to be protected **by your server** before it ever gets to the client.

Answer (score 0):

So I agree with what jfriend00 mentioned but I'll add my perspective as well.

> For my frontend javascript file do I need to split into two files so one js file is for all the public routes pages and another one is for all private routes pages? if I just use one client side js file for both public and private routes view pages is there going to be any kind of security issues?

Like the other comment, this isn't a really a security concern. If you're writing front-end JS, the only potential security breach is if you include API keys, tokens, secrets, etc. But this goes against best practices anyway. So splitting files really only comes down to organizational structure.

That being said, if you have JS code that is only relevant to handling your back-end routes and other back-end logic, you can create a folder (that isn't served to the client) to hold back-end JS files. That way, your code is organized and you wouldn't be exposing any logic that you may or may not wish to keep hidden. An example of this could be a form validator for the login page.

That's just another use case I thought might be helpful. But I believe what you want to achieve is just manipulating DOM elements which shouldn't pose a security threat. If you think about it, anyone can modify DOM elements via their browser's dev tools. But it doesn't hurt your data, server-side logic or anything else really.